# Creating anamorphic typography in CAD program

Tags: gratis, 3d, cad

For my current project I´m trying to create anamorphic typography on 3D objects. The program most be able to project an image, in my case typography, to the surface of objects. My husband showed me that this can be done in SolidWorks with creating [projection split lines](http://help.solidworks.com/2013/English/SolidWorks/sldworks/t_Creating_Projection_Split_Lines.htm).

But SolidWorks is not a free program and way above my league as I have no experience with CAD programs.

I looked for tutorials for Sketch-Up and Unity, but I cannot find how to create the desired effect in these programs. Is there a free, preferably basic CAD program in which an image can be projected on complex surfaces of objects?

Example (in SolidWorks):
[image: Projected text in front view]

[image: Projected text in side view]

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but I'd bet you can do this in [**OnShape**](https://www.onshape.com/). In fact, I'd be surprised if you can't do *almost* anything you can do in SolidWorks in OnShape.

Worth a look I think:

https://forum.onshape.com/discussion/1895/tutorial-how-to-create-raised-text-on-a-curved-surface

Hope that helps - oh and seeing as you are familiar with SolidWorks, I should note that OnShape was co-founded by the co-founder of SolidWorks, Jon Hirschtick.

https://www.onshape.com/cad-blog/why-we-started-from-scratch-again-in-the-cad-business